# How to access attributes of the 'User' model extended by another model referenced by a OnetoOneField in admin.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In model.py, I have a class extending the User model

```
class Tutor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In admin.py, I tried to access user.id with 'user_id', which works

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'contact_number')
```

[image]

However, when I try to access other attributes of 'user' such as username, email with this format

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'user_username', 'contact_number')
```

This occurs
[image]

What is the format to access attributes such as user.username or user.email?

**UPDATE**

Solved it with

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @admin.display(description='username')
    def username(self):
        u = self.user
        if u is not None:
            return u.username

    @admin.display(description='email')
    def email(self):
        u = self.user
        if u is not None:
            return u.email


    list_display = ('user_id', username, email, 'contact_number')
```

Thanks to the solution by [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893565/how-to-access-attributes-of-the-user-model-extended-by-another-model-reference/67893628#67893628)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define methods and reference these in the `list_display`:

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'contact_number', username)

    @admin.display(description='username')
    def username(self, obj):
        u = obj.user
        if u is not None:
            return u.username
```

You can however not edit the usernames, since the function defines how to access the data, not how to alter it.

Since the `__str__` for the builtin `User` model returns the username, you can also work with:

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'contact_number', user)
```